# Detailed Bathymetric/Bathymetry contour data (0-200M)

Tags: shapefile, data, contour, bathymetry, north-america

I am looking for free *Bathymetric contour data* in shapefile format for depths between 0-200 meters for North America. I prefer contours at 10 meter increments, but will take whatever I can get.

I have found Bathymetric layers for 0 and 200 meters from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/. However, I need more detail within that range.

My questions are:

- Where can I find freely available Bathymetric data between 0-200 meters for North America?
- How did you find the data and what did you use to search for it?

Comment: There's a lot of bathymetric data to be found at [NOAA National Geophysical Data Center](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/relief.html) but those data will likely be rasters, not shapefiles.  You can produce contour lines from the rasters.

Answer (score 4):

Worldwide bathymetry data in .nc extension format can be obtained from [here](https://www.bodc.ac.uk/data/online_delivery/gebco/) at the following resolution:

**The GEBCO One Minute Grid** — a global one arc-minute grid
Released: 2003, updated: 2008 — largely based on the most recent set of bathymetric contours contained within the GEBCO Digital Atlas.
The GEBCO_08 Grid — a global 30 arc-second grid

You can select data with bounds.
The .nc file can be manipulate using a suitable gis program to generate depth contours which can then be exported as a shapefile.

Answer (score 3):

Try these links: [IHO](http://www.iho.int/srv1/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=304&Itemid=696) and [NOAA](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/multibeam.html)

Google bathymetric data download

Bathymetry shape files here  http://gcoos.tamu.edu/products/topography/Shapefiles.html