# Need shapefile for worldwide bathymetry

Tags: shapefile, bathymetry

I need a (free, no cost) shapefile for bathymetry of entire world, specifically from depths of zero to 200 metres, ideally in 50 or 100 m contour intervals. Has to be a shapefile. Help please!

Answer (score 1):

Similar question and answers can be found here:
[Detailed Bathymetric/Bathymetry contour data (0-200M)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45334/detailed-bathymetric-bathymetry-contour-data-0-200m)

Hope that helps

meryloo